# Joining multiple Pandas data frames into one

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have list (**lst**) of data frames and my list has 2000 dataframes. I want to combine all of these data frames in one. Each dataframe has two columns and the first column of each dataframe is the same. For example:

```
#First dataframe
>>lst[0]
    0          1 
   11         6363
   21         737
   34          0
   43          0

#Second dataframe 
>>lst[1]
    0          1 
   11         33
   21          0
   34         937
   43          0

#third dataframe 
>>lst[2]
    0          1 
   11          73
   21          18
   34          27
   43          77
```

Final dataframe will look like:

```
    0          1            2          3
   11         6363          33         73
   21         737           0          18
   34          0            937        27
   43          0            0          77
```

How can I achieve that? Insights will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First we can set the first column as an index to ignore it in concatenation

```
lst = [df.set_index(0) for df in lst]
```

Then we concatenate the columns and drop the 0 column back to being the column instead of the index

```
df_out = pd.concat(lst, axis=1).reset_index()
```

And we rename the columns:

```
df_out.columns = range(df_out.shape[1])
```

Result is:

```
>> df_out
    0     1    2   3 ...
0  11  6363   33  73 ...
1  21   737    0  18 ...
2  34     0  937  27 ...
3  43     0    0  77 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```py
lst = [df0, df1, df2, ...]

# Merge dataframes
df_all = lst[0]
for df in lst[1:]:
    df_all = df_all.merge(df, how="outer", on=0)

# Rename columns of final dataframe
df_all.columns = list(range(df_all.shape[1]))

print(df_all)
# Outputs
    0     1    2   3 ...
0  11  6363   33  73 ...
1  21   737    0  18 ...
2  34     0  937  27 ...
3  43     0    0  77 ...
```